# How to hide rows with specific data in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with several rows. I want to select some rows with specific rownames (only 1 and 0) and avoid rows with the values N and X (as highlighted in the picture). This dataframe is as follows:

[Picture]

The result would be as the following:

The reason for this is due to the fact that I'd like to use `plot(TONICIDADE, VD)` without including rows containing `N` and `X` in the plot. I wouldn't like to delete the rows with `N` and `X`, just wouldn't like them to be shown when plotting.

Comment: `subset(df1, VD %in% c(1, 0))`

Answer (score 1):

#### General thoughts on data manipulation

You're approaching this from a spreadsheet mindset, where data manipulation always messes up your original dataset and where it's expensive and cumbersome to make copies. In R, we don't hide parts of a data frame, we make copies that have only the parts (or modifications) we're interested in.

I don't have your dataset, so I'll use `iris`:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

There are many ways to remove rows. I prefer `filter()` from the dplyr package. For example, to remove cases with `Sepal.Length >= 5`, I could enter:

```
> iris2 <- filter(iris, Sepal.Length < 5)
> head(iris2)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
3          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
5          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
```

(You tell `filter()` what you want to keep, not what you want to remove.)

It's also possible to use the pipe operator `%>%` to feed the modified data frame right into the next function. You do this if you want to filter only once and use the result right away. So, if I wanted to filter and then plot, I could do:

```
filter(iris, Sepal.Length < 5) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Unfortunately the base-R `plot()` function doesn't take data frames as input, so the pipe approach requires that you plot with `ggplot()`.

#### Solving your specific problem

To your specific problem: To filter out a specific list of values, you can generally use the `!variable %in% c(...)` pattern, where `variable` is the variable you want to filter on and `c(...)` is the vector of things you want to exclude, e.g.:

```
filter(data, !VD %in% c('N', 'X'))
```

And you use the same pattern without the `!` to list the values you want to include rather than exclude.

Examples:

```
> data <- data.frame(VD = c("1", "0", "X", "N", "1"), values = rnorm(5))
> data
  VD      values
1  1 -0.56295856
2  0  0.36063581
3  X  0.06490702
4  N -0.23342063
5  1 -0.18901558
> filter(data, !VD %in% c('N', 'X'))
  VD     values
1  1 -0.5629586
2  0  0.3606358
3  1 -0.1890156
> filter(data, VD %in% c('0', '1'))
  VD     values
1  1 -0.5629586
2  0  0.3606358
3  1 -0.1890156
```